# TestRig in Eclipse with ANTLR4 IDE for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr4

I have installed ANTLR 4 IDE for Eclipse in my Eclipse software. I want to test the grammar directly from Eclipse by using TestRig found in antlr-4*.jar file.

I found this way of testing the antlr4 grammar in TestRig using CLI (at url
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4):

```
SET CLASSPATH=C:\Javalib\antlr-4.2.1-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%
run.bat:   java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %*
```

How can I configure Eclipse to make this test configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in ***Parse Tree*** view tab.
To enable this tab please go Windows->Show view->Other..->Search for ANTLR4